# What crime is Shay D. Guy commiting?

Tags: story, situation

Nobody trusted Guy. He always seemed to be up to something. Unfortunately, the police couldn't lock him up, simply because they had no evidence against him. Not even the circumstantial kind.

Guy worked at a factory, the kind that made construction products. It was a dirty, low paying job, but it was the only place in town that dare hire Guy. The factory was filled with security cameras, so they were confident that Guy could not get away with his devious schemes.

As expected, Guy shows some suspicious behavior. Every night at 9:28, just minutes before the factory closes, Guy leaves with a wheelbarrow filled with scrap parts. The security footage clearly shows that there is nothing of value inside. Despite this, the owner of the factory is still suspicious.

> What is Shay D. Guy up to?

Comment: What I don't like about this sort of puzzle is that makes no sense in-universe; the puzzle is guessing a piece of information that in-universe everyone always knows, so it makes no sense that he's allowed to do this every night.

Comment: @Acccumulation The owner is puzzled as to why Guy is lurking around, alone, seemingly doing nothing wrong.

Comment: But based on what the owner knows, Guy would not be "seemingly doing nothing wrong". He's taking wheelbarrows full of scrap parts out of the factory. It's only by not mentioning that gur snpgbel znxrf jurryoneebjf that it's not obvious what's going on. How can the owner be puzzled? Does the owner not know that gur snpgbel znxrf jurryoneebjf? Does the owner not know that Guy is leaving with the wheelbarrows? Presumbably, Guy is gnxvat n oenaq arj jurryoneebj bss gur nffrzoyl yvar naq svyyvat vg jvgu fpenc. How is that not suspicious?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shay D. Guy is

> **Stealing wheelbarrows**!

The factory is one where they make

> wheelbarrows, and by filling it with scrap, Shay is misdirecting the attention of the security staff to its contents, not the wheelbarrow itself.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Phylyp's answer

> Even though the scrap parts aren't of value, they had to come from the factory, right? That's still stealing.

Comment: Scrap is actually worth quite a lot, probably more than the wheelbarrows. 10kg of stainless steel (that's less than 2 liters, or $\frac{1}{120}$ hogsheads) probably fetches around 10 $/€/£, copper about 4 times as much.